# Gallery QPKG Plugin on a QNAP TS 209

Tags: php, iconv, qnap

I have a QNAP TS 209 firmware version: 3.3.2 Build 0918T. (as far as I know the last official version)
I've installed successfully the Gallery plugin but when starting is I get the following error:

There are some problems with your web hosting environment that need to be fixed before you can successfully install Gallery 3.
PHP is missing the iconv extension

In fact it is true. Php has been compiled explicitly without iconv. phpinfo() shows the following configure command:

'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache/conf/php.ini' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/config/php.d' '--with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--disable-ipv6' '**--without-iconv**' '--with-zlib-dir' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--with-gd' '--with-freetype-dir' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-openssl-dir' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/cross-project/ARM/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sys-root' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-exif' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' '--with-curl=/opt/cross-project/ARM/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sys-root' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-shared'

and this is the reason why Gallery is NOT working.

My question is how to install/compile php under this box?
Or is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most QNAP appliances run Linux, they're based on embedded hardware instead of x86.  In this case, it looks like you're running on ARM.  This makes it *very* unlikely that you're going to find a precompiled package for the iconv extension.

Chances are that you are going to need to acquire the [iconv library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), the specific version of PHP that they selected, and manually compile the extension yourself, or manually recompile PHP as a whole with the extension included.

If this is the first time you've ever compiled PHP or a PHP extension, you *might* want to try it on an x86 Linux machine first, just to get the hang of it.

It's possible that you might be able to use their official ["QPKG" building mechanism](http://forum.qnap.com/viewforum.php?f=253) to accomplish the compile.  Unfortunately the [developer forum](http://forum.qnap.com/viewforum.php?f=131) is behind a login wall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact at the NAS there is no compiler available. I suppose I have to install some SDK for compiling PHP from scratch. To try that on an x86 is also a good idea. I will take a look at the developer's forum. Thanks again (+1)